# Toggle page color with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use JS to change my page's color theme by click a button, and by clicking it again to change it back (i.e. toggle). So far this is my JS code:

```
var i = 0;

function changeColor() {
    if (i%2 == 0) {
        switchBlue();
    } else {
        switchGreen();
    }
    i++;
}

function switchBlue() {
    document.getElementById('color-wrap-01').style.backgroundColor = "#07184a";
    document.getElementById('color-wrap-02').style.backgroundColor = "#006385";
    document.getElementById('color-wrap-03').style.backgroundColor = "#82baba";
    document.getElementById('color-wrap-04').style.backgroundColor = "#082644";
    document.getElementById('box').style.backgroundColor = "#d0dddd";
    document.getElementById('vl-01').style.borderLeft = "4px solid blue";
    document.getElementById('vl-02').style.borderLeft = "4px solid blue";

    var footerText = document.getElementsByClassName('footer-text');
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        footerText[i].style.color = "#8eb7ba";
    }

    var headerText = document.getElementsByClassName('header-text');
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        headerText[i].style.color = "#81babd";
    }

    var subTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('sub-title');
    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        subTitle[i].style.color = "#008688";
    }
}

function switchGreen() {
    document.getElementById('color-wrap-01').style.backgroundColor = "#074946";
    document.getElementById('color-wrap-02').style.backgroundColor = "#00865F";
    document.getElementById('color-wrap-03').style.backgroundColor = "#81BA88";
    document.getElementById('color-wrap-04').style.backgroundColor = "#084330";
    document.getElementById('box').style.backgroundColor = "#D7DDD0";
    document.getElementById('vl-01').style.borderLeft = "4px solid green";
    document.getElementById('vl-02').style.borderLeft = "4px solid green";
    var footerText = document.getElementsByClassName('footer-text');
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        footerText[i].style.color = "green";
    }

    var headerText = document.getElementsByClassName('header-text');
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        headerText[i].style.color = "green";
    }

    var subTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('sub-title');
    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        subTitle[i].style.color = "green";
    }
}
```

with this html:

```
 <div id="color-wrap-01">
     <div class="container">
             <div class="row top-header">
                 <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p align="left">Welcome, Guest <a href="https://www.google.ca/">Login</a>  <a href="https://www.google.ca/">Sign Up</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p align="right">Stay Updated: <a href="https://www.google.ca/">Subscribe via RSS</a> <a href="https://www.google.ca/">Email Updates</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

AND this button:

```
<button onclick="changeColor()">COLOUR</button>
```

The first color change works, but then after that the button doesn't switch back to Green. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hmm, maybe try to move your i++ right before calling your function switchBlue() and switchGreen()?

Comment: So I did a bit of debugging and it works without the for loops inside of switchBlue() and switchGreen() (for changing entire class elements). Any idea why this could be?

Comment: Well you don't have any element matching "color-wrap-04"... so that is giving you an error.

Comment: Try to use different variable name in your for loop, for example : for (var k = 0; k<11; k++), maybe using the same variable is causing issue here? I can only guess, I haven't tried it, let me know!

Comment: why don't you add a class to the body and apply the blue colors when that class is present? it's a lot cleaner, add the css for `body.blue #color-wrap-01` and so on, then you only need to toggle the class `blue` on the body element, same for the color green

Comment: They're different shades of blue and green. But I agree it'd be a lot cleaner

Comment: @JimmySurprenant my variables names for each function had to be different! so i changed footerText to footerTextB and footerTextG Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to toggle between two colors, you can do like this :

```
var colorSwitch = '';
function changeColor() {
    if (colorSwitch === '') {
        switchBlue();
        colorSwitch = 'blue';
    } else {
        switchGreen();
        colorSwitch = '';
    }
}
```

Thats just an idea, but you may not need an iterator.
You can test that here : https://jsfiddle.net/qwu41fno/